# is possible creating Geowebcache tiles offline

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geowebcache

When I start geowebcache seed mechanism, my server CPU is working %120 persentage. And I can not use WMS service on my openlayers application because it is working very slow. Server sources are consuming by geowebcache.

Can I create tiles offline via QGIS or another application.

Geowebcache cache directory is like this:

- cache/topp_states/EPSG_2163_00/0_0/00_00.png
- cache/topp_states/EPSG_2163_00/0_0/00_01.png
- cache/topp_states/EPSG_2163_00/0_0/01_00.png
- cache/topp_states/EPSG_2163_00/0_0/01_01.png

Comment: You could run your tile jobs during the off-work-hours (at night) using a cron and the REST capabilities of GWC.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
there is no official support for anything like that.

However, I would suggest to seed only the lowest zoom levels and let GWC build the other upon request. You might want to play with the metatling size to reduce the penalty to pay when you'll get cache misses.

Simone.